# Finding the mean of an unknown distribution.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

[image: Problem]

I solved the integral and it's theta, but i'm not sure how to get the mean of the distribution because i don't know the kind of distribution i'm dealing with.

Any ideas? i'd really appreciate your help. =)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with density $x\mapsto\frac1\theta x^{(1-\theta)/\theta}\mathbf{1}_{0<x<1}$ for some $\theta>0$. Then the mean of $X$ (or of the distribution) is 
$$
{\rm E}[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\frac1\theta x^{(1-\theta)/\theta}\mathbf{1}_{0<x<1}\,\mathrm dx=\frac1\theta\int_0^1 x^{1/\theta}\,\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: Are you missing an $x$ in the integrals? According to the question, the integral of $\frac{1}{\theta}x^{(1-\theta)/\theta}\mathbf 1_{0 < x < 1}$ is $1$ which would be an unusual value for $E[X]$ in this problem.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Yes I missed an $x$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The expectation of a random variable, $X$, is defined as 
$$\int xd\mu$$
where $\mu$ is the probability measure that $X$ follows. In other words the expectation of this distribution will be simply 
$$\int x\left\{\frac{1}{\theta}x^{(1-\theta)/\theta}\right\}dx$$